# formatting date variable doesn't work

Tags: sas

I am doing data step using the following code.

```
data meme;
infile '/home/bronx.txt' dlm='09'x truncover firstobs=2;
length ADDRESS $12. DATE 8. GROSS 5. LAND 8. SALE 6. YEAR 4. ZIP 6.;
format DATE mmddyy10.;
input ADDRESS $ ZIP LAND GROSS YEAR SALE DATE;

run;
```

Nonetheless, this error always accures:

> WARNING: Limit set by ERRORS= option reached. Further errors of this type will not be printed.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you do not understand what SAS formats and informats are for.

A **FORMAT** is instructions for converting the stored value into text.  To go the otther way you need to use an **INFORMAT**.  So if the text in your file looks like `01/01/2016` then you would want to use the `MMDDYY` informat (or perhaps the `DDMMYY` informat). If it looks like `01JAN2016` then you will want to use the `DATE` informat.  If you want to value to look like dates when printed then you should also apply one of the many date formats.

It also looks like you do not understand how the `LENGTH` statement works. In a `LENGTH` statement you need to specify the lengths for the variable, not formats.   The **LENGTH** of a SAS variable is the number of bytes used to store the value in the dataset. Since SAS uses 64-bit floating point format for all numbers you should use a length of 8 for numbers.  (You can store numbers using fewer bytes but that just means SAS throws away the lower order bytes when writing to the dataset.)

You might try something more like this:

```
data meme;
  infile '/home/bronx.txt' dlm='09'x truncover firstobs=2;
  length ADDRESS $12 ZIP LAND GROSS YEAR SALE DATE 8;
  format DATE mmddyy10.;
  informat DATE mmddyy.;
  input ADDRESS ZIP LAND GROSS YEAR SALE DATE;
run;
```